# AWS IOT Connection for MQTT

Tags: android, mqtt, aws-sdk

How to make connection AWS with IOT for MQTT. I have three files `certificate.pem.crt`, `private.poem.key` and `public.poem.key` and server url of AWS.

Comment: Why down vote if you don't know.

Comment: Explain what you have already tried and show the code you are using. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have tried from <https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub/src/com/amazonaws/demo/androidpubsub>